# APC false alarm?

Tags: linux, ups

I have an APC Back-UPS 1500RS attached to a Gentoo server that's less than 2 years old.  I've already replaced the battery once on this thing and am getting replace battery messages again.  I'm not quite sure if the problem is in the the UPS system or in the software:  if I run a battery calibration the message goes away for a little while.

Here's the output of apcaccess:

```
# apcaccess 
APC      : 001,037,0937
DATE     : 2016-02-21 09:49:01 -0500  
HOSTNAME : alaya
VERSION  : 3.14.8 (16 January 2010) gentoo
UPSNAME  : alaya
CABLE    : USB Cable
MODEL    : Back-UPS RS 1500G 
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2016-02-18 13:37:26 -0500  
STATUS   : ONLINE REPLACEBATT 
LINEV    : 120.0 Volts
LOADPCT  :  20.0 Percent Load Capacity
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT :  34.3 Minutes
MBATTCHG : 5 Percent
MINTIMEL : 3 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 0 Seconds
SENSE    : Medium
LOTRANS  : 088.0 Volts
HITRANS  : 147.0 Volts
ALARMDEL : Always
BATTV    : 27.0 Volts
LASTXFER : Unacceptable line voltage changes
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : NO
STATFLAG : 0x07000088 Status Flag
MANDATE  : 2013-10-13
SERIALNO : 4B1341P44760  
BATTDATE : 2014-10-13
NOMINV   : 120 Volts
NOMBATTV :  24.0 Volts
NOMPOWER : 865 Watts
FIRMWARE : 865.L5 .D USB FW:L5
APCMODEL : Back-UPS RS 1500G 
END APC  : 2016-02-21 09:49:37 -0500
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you replace the batteries with official batteries from APC or third party generics?  The original batteries should have lasted at least 3 yrs, same with OEM replacements.  There are cheap generic junk batteries on the market that can have much shorter life (no excuse for the originals, though).  What did you base the need for replacement on, and what is indicating end-of-life now?  It could be that the original and current batteries are fine and some indicator light is giving false warnings.

Comment: Sorry for the hiatus!  I feel like the battery is actually o.k.  The display itself says there are about 45 minutes of life left, and whenver I do a test the message that the battery is off disappears.  I'm a little confused about the display.  Does a battery with an "X" over it mean it needs replacing?

Again, when I do a test by holding power button for 6secs that icon goes away...

Answer (score 0):

First check that all battery connectors and connectors to the inverter are tight, are not corroded, and do not have many broken strands at the end. Cable resistance could appear to be a weak battery when load testing.

Second, test the battery with an accurate voltmeter and the expected load (~40 Amperes at "NOMPOWER" or nominal power output of 865 Watts, if the inverter is ~90% efficient). The [voltage should stay at or above ~22 Volts](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/what_is_the_c_rate) for three minutes (MINTIMEL, or minimum battery runtime under load until system shutdown). Note that these batteries (2x12 volts) are designed for low capacity (8 Ah) but heavy current drain (5*C [capacity in Ah]) so that terminal EMF should be ~1.8-1.9 V/cell under load. If the battery passes this heavy test (which should not be repeated often, as it could shorten the battery life), then the UPS calibration is in error and, in that case, you might contact APC for software update or UPS replacement under warranty.

If the battery *is* failing, then the cause of the issue might be improper charging or frequent use or testing under heavy load. Do not run frequent heavy-load tests. High temperature in the server room and running the UPS until exhaustion can also shorten battery life.

The good news is that I've seen replacement batteries for [~US$30.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073XFBHO)

Comment: Good answer, but I'm curious where 22 volts came from.

Comment: I still wasn't able to figure out the 22V (we may be interpreting the linked article differently & can chat offline if you have time).  It's possible that the only problem is a false battery warning (the output listing in the question doesn't look like an almost dead battery).  An easy check: the APC [specs page](http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/Power-Saving-Back-UPS-XS-1500/P-BX1500G) includes a link to a runtime chart that gives expected runtime based on load.  At 100% of original capacity, it should power a 100W incandescent light for about 70 mins.  That would be a simple 1st step.

Comment: Thanks for the tip DrMoishe!  I will work on getting a voltmeter and giving this a try.